# How can I use await to fetch data from DB using Bookshelf js?

Tags: node.js, promise, bookshelf.js

I am looking for a way to get data usign await, below is the code.

```
// Await this set of things
    var getResponse = await('pr', 'chat');
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("done!");
    });

let chat = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    User
    .where('id', req.body.application_id)
    .fetch({withRelated: ['company']})
    .then(function(result, err) {
        resolve(result);
    });
});

getResponse.keep('pr', promise);
getResponse.keep('chat', chat);


getResponse.then(function(response) {

    console.log('in to reponse:-', response);

    res.status(200).send(response);

},function(err) {

  res.status(400).json({'error' : "Error while fetching data"});
});
```

Getting response on console is `{ pr: Promise { 'done!' }, chat: Promise { <pending> } }`

Response on browser

```
{
    "pr": {},
    "chat": {}
}
```

Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/await and http://bookshelfjs.org/

Comment: The question isn't related to `async-await`. Why would you use a dated lib like await.js in Node? I didn't use it but I'm positive the thing you're trying to achieve is possible with plain promises and especially with async..await.

Comment: Thanks for the information @estus. I am new to Node and trying things which I found over the internet by doing a light search, await's npm page  is showing an example in  Node so I thought of using. Would be using doing this with plain promises now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may avoid extra library by using native `Promise.all()` function, following example, may help you

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("done!");
});

//User.where().fetch() return a promise
let chat = User
    .where('id', req.body.application_id)
    .fetch({
        withRelated: ['company']
    });


Promise.all([promise, chat])
    .then(function (response) {
        var data = {
            promise: response[0],
            chat: response[1]
        }

        console.log('in to reponse:-', response);

        res.status(200).send(data);

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            'error': "Error while fetching data"
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Arif That worked well. I am looking for one more thing here, Want to move this query into a  function and then read the Promise, It is not allowing me to do that. Something just like this

let chat = chatFunctions.getDetails(req.body.application_id);
And in my chatFunctions file 
chatFunctions.getDetails = function(application_id) {
 ChatApplication
 .where('id', application_id)
 .fetch({withRelated: ['company']});
}

I have tried return Promise which did not work. Can you suggest me something here?

Comment: seems like you forgot to return like `return ChatApplication.where('id', application_id).fetch({withRelated: ['company']});`